# What is command to look list of redirect rules, iptables

Tags: linux, command-line, iptables

im using command like this :

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.118 --dport 4080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.118:4088`

My question what is command to look all rules in the selected chain. I'm using `iptables -L` but it doesn't display anything. But, that's command is successfull to redirect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
iptables -L -t nat
```

use the table name with -t

Comment: Thx it works. Then, how to delete the rules?

Comment: In the command that you have specified use -D instead of -A .